# Can InstallShield use environment variables in part of a source file path at built time?

Tags: installshield

We have a build script which build three types of projects - C++, Java and finally the respective InstallShield installers.

Right now the installer build script relies on the fact that the C++ projects are always built in the Release configuration.

But now I wish to allow building them in an additional configuration, namely Profile.

We are using the Jenkins CI server and thus the desired configuration is provided through a dedicated Jenkins build parameter `DRIVER_PROXY_CONFIG`, which is surfaced as an environment variable with the same name.

Now the problem. According to our InstallShield guy, IS cannot use an environment variable in part of a source file path. I quote:

> You can use or 'environment variable' or 'user-defined path variables
>   defined through InstallShield' as file path.
>
> So we can:
>
> 1. Create 'environment variable' for each component (since 'DRIVER_PROXY_CONFIG' is only part of the component path) – not desirable.
> 2. Make the 'environment variable' part of the component 'user-defined path variable' – not possible, I have just tried it.

Has anyone done anything like this? The installer depends on multiple source files in different locations, where a part of such a location path is the value of the `DRIVER_PROXY_CONFIG` environment variable. Note that this part is neither the path prefix nor the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can create it as part of a path. Some exact behaviors do depend on the version of InstallShield, but for the last several you can even use relative parent directories. Just go to the Path Variables view, add a new environment path variable (say `Env`), and set the environment variable it references. Then either add any number of standard path variables (say `Stn`) that are defined as `<Env>\Sub\Dir`, or skip this step and just reference those for the `ISBuildSourcePath` of the relevant files. Typically adding a file from a path under a defined path variable will use that path variable as part of its path.

If you've already added the files, the convert source paths wizard may help here, but you might find it easier to visit the File table directly to update the `ISBuildSourcePath`

However there is at least one exception. If your environment variable has the value `Sub` and your full directory name is `SubDirectory`, you cannot always reference `<Env>Directory`. Typically the path variable support will turn that into `Sub\Directory` instead.

Comment: On behalf of Gilad: What if 'env' is not prefix nor suffix of the path ("SomeDir\<env>\SubDir")?

I have created system env config=release
I have created IS variable 'MyConf' that reference the env 'config'
I have created IS standard path MyPath = "SomeDir\<MyConf>\SubDir"

If I add file from this path - IS won't suggest 'MyPath' as suggested path!!!

The only way I have found, is to add the files, and then visit the File table directly to update the ISBuildSourcePath.

Comment: Oh, if the issue is using it as the middle of the path, I'll have to double check. On the bright side it sounds like modifying the File table is a workaround, but it's always best when you don't have to think to do things correctly.

Comment: We did not find a way to use it in the middle of the path. Makes the life needlessly harder.

Answer (score 2):

Michael:

What if 'env' is not prefix nor suffix of the path (`"SomeDir\<env>\SubDir"`)?

I have created system env `config=release`
I have created IS variable 'MyConf' that reference the env 'config'
I have created IS standard path `MyPath = "SomeDir\<MyConf>\SubDir"`

If I add file from this path - IS won't suggest 'MyPath' as suggested path!!!

The only way I have found, is to add the files, and then visit the File table directly to update the ISBuildSourcePath.

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO, Gilad. You could ask me to write a comment to Michael :-)

Answer (score 0):

I added the environment variable as a path variable, ytou can set environment variable types here (not string types!)

then you can use that anywhere you'd use a path variable - though I did have to enclose it in square brackets rather than the usual angle ones). It should work in the middle of a path as I have done that with ordinary path variables.